# Getting the socketId in the route request

Tags: node.js, socket.io, mean-stack

How to get the socket ID of the client within the route request.

For example,

```
io.on('connection',function(socket)
{
    var socketId = socket.id;
}

router.get('/',function(req, res){
{
    let socket = io.sockets.sockets[socketId];
    // How can I get the socketId of the client sending this request
}
```

When I declare the socketId as a global variable, it does not work when multiple users use the application.

Would help, if a solution is proposed for this. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think one way to handle is to relate a random hash to that socket id and send it to frontend when socket first connects. User can provide that hash when making a get request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an id as query string during the handshake, store this id on server, and have the client sending this id to server every time for authentication. For example:

`client.js`:

```
const clientId = "some_unique_id";
const socket = io('http://localhost?id=' + clientId);

fetch('http://localhost?some_key=some_value&id=' + clientId).then(/*...*/);
```

`server.js`:

```
const io = require('socket.io')();

// this should be a database or a cache
const idToConnectionHash = {};

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  let id = socket.handshake.query.id;

  idToConnectionHash[id] = socket.id;
  // ...
});

router.get('/',function(req, res){
  let socket = idToConnectionHash[req.query.id];
  // ...
}
```